# No sound from applications after Ubuntu LTS 18.04 wakes up

Tags: sound

I am unable to hear sound from applications running on laptop.  For example, I am getting no sound from Youtube videos regardless of whether I view them in Firefox or Chromium.  I observed this when the machine awoke from a lid-down sleep this morning.

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on a machine built by Zareason.  I have no external speakers.

I have worked through the diagnostics provided at https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/sound-nosound.html.en, without success.

- On Activities/Settings/Sound, I have "Speakers - Built-in Audio".  The Output Volume is set to maximum.  The profile is set to "Analog Stereo Output" and is equally balanced between Left and Right. Clicking on "Test Speakers", both Front Left and Front Right test properly.
- On the keyboard, Fn+RightArrow emits a beep when pressed.  So I'm not muting from the keyboard.
- lspci shows:

$ lspci -v | grep -i audio
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller

- I have rebooted the computer, with no impact on sound.
- I have performed 'sudo apt-get dist-upgrade', with no impact on sound.
- I have also performed the steps described at https://www.unixmen.com/2012wget http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-info.sh && bash ./alsa-info.sh --upload;003-howto-resolve-nosound-problem-on-ubuntu/, with no impact on sound.

sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio
sudo apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio
sudo alsa force-reload

At the terminal I typed 'alsamixer'.  I have "Card: HDA Intel HDMI"; Chip: Intel Haswell HDMI; View: Playback; Item S/PDIF.  I have a row of 5 icons in which "S/PDIF" is selected.  It has a little box above it with setting "00", which I have not yet been able to adjust (e.g., via the UpArrow, Shift-+ or PageUp keys.

Suggestions?

Comment: Further bad news:  After an additional reboot of the machine, in Activities/Settings/Sound/Test Speakers I get no sound on either FrontLeft or FrontRight.

Answer (score 3):

I have stumbled on a solution -- though perhaps not the best solution -- to this problem.

I installed the program 'pavucontrol':  `sudo apt-get install pavucontrol`.

In the program's Configuration tab I observed **two** Profiles.  The first was "Digital Stereo (HDMI 3) Output (unplugged)".  The second was "Built-in Audio."

I turned the first configuration to `Off`.  The second configuration was set to `Analog Stereo Duplex`.

The pavucontrol Output Devices tab now reports on "Built-in Audio Analog Stereo.  I am now getting expected audio in Firefox, Chromium and Rhythmbox.  This restored performance has survived a reboot.

The one place where I am not getting my previous performance is in Activities/Settings/Sound/Test Speakers, where I am getting no sound out of either FrontLeft or FrontRight.

I have a hypothesis as to what happened.  Four days ago I was giving a presentation where my laptop was connected to a data projector via an HDMI cable.  At the end of the presentation I shutdown my laptop but did not take the HDMI cable out until after the machine was off.

Could that have "reset" the sound configuration to "expect" HTMI as "default"?

Comment: Wow. I experienced the this today. I disconnected the HDMI cable from my laptop without switching back to the default audio. There ought to be auto switching in Linux like in Windows. Your solution helped :)